# Delete all records from related tables using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables.

```
Posts
Likes
Post_images.

// Model Relations.
Posts hasMany likes.
Likes belongs to Posts.
post hasMany PostImages
post_imags belongs to Posts.
```

Now when i delete a post record i want to delete its related records from likes table as well as from post_images table,Besides this images should also be removed from storage.

How can i accomplish this ? any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you defined relationships between tables using eloquent  ?
show your  table relations

Comment: I have  updated the question @Rodrane

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your query should be like this. But you **cannot remove** images with eloquent relations. So you need to do something like

```
 $courses = \App\Course::all();
 foreach($courses $ $course){
      Storage::delete($course->image_column_name);
 }

 \App\Courses::with('sessions')->with('lessons')->delete();
```

I can give you better answer if you can share your models function, database schema and Storage information like where you store course images...

Comment: Please have a look into this URL,its has complete relationships.
https://kopy.io/q5gDL

Comment: \App\Courses::with('sessions')->with('lessons')->delete(); try this

Comment: thank you,it would work,but how can i delete the images as well ?

Comment: Thank you,this is what i was looking for

Comment: Hey @KhiradBanu, if he answered the question, you should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('users')->delete();
```

All users are deleted from 'user' Table

Answer (score 0):

if you set table names with Models::table('abilities') in

```
    Schema::create(Models::table('abilities'), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        // other fields
    }
```

you can use

```
    DB::table(Models::table('abilities'))->delete();
```

as documented here you can

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
   Models::table('abilities');
}
```